# How to set the scrolling threshold for a react native ScrollView to switch to next/previous page

Tags: react-native

I currently have a ScrollView/Flatlist containing 4 items with paging enabled. When rendered, each item covers the entire screen in portrait mode. On Android, when the user tries to swipe vertically from one item to another, this requires "large" swipe gestures.

I am trying to increase the "sensitivity" of the react native ScrollView so that the user requires smaller swipe gestures to switch from one item to another.

At the moment the switch to the next/previous page requires that roughly 50% of the target page is visible. I want to reduce this value so that the user does not need to do big swipe gestures.

Any suggestions on how I could fine-tune the props of the ScrollView/FlatList would be great!

Comment: any update on this, did you able to do this?